# How do you transpose a table in a generalizable way in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, transpose

How would you transpose this table:

**old_table**

```
+----+--------+-------------+-------------------+
| id | type   | field       | value             |
+----+--------+-------------+-------------------+
| 1  | person | gender      | female            |
+----+--------+-------------+-------------------+
| 1  | person | age         | 22                |
+----+--------+-------------+-------------------+
| 1  | person | name        | Julie Smith       |
+----+--------+-------------+-------------------+
| 1  | person | picture_url | www.pic.com/1.jpg |
+----+--------+-------------+-------------------+
| 2  | person | gender      | male              |
+----+--------+-------------+-------------------+
| 2  | person | name        | Johnny Parsons    |
+----+--------+-------------+-------------------+
```

into a table like this:

**new_table**

```
+----+----------------+--------+------+-------------------+
| id | name           | gender | age  | picture_url       |
+----+----------------+--------+------+-------------------+
| 1  | Julie Smith    | female | 22   | www.pic.com/1.jpg |
+----+----------------+--------+------+-------------------+
| 2  | Johnny Parsons | male   | Null | Null              |
+----+----------------+--------+------+-------------------+
```

We could do a query like this:

```
INSERT INTO new_table SELECT
id::id as id,
max(case when field='name' then value else null end) as name,
max(case when field='gender' then value else null end) as gender,
max(case when field='age' then value else null end) as age,
max(case when field='picture_url' then value else null end) as picture_url
FROM old_table
WHERE 1=1
AND type = 'person'
GROUP BY
id
;
```

Unfortunately, this query is not generalizable and if I were to add new fields, then those fields would not be added to the new table. Is there a way to write a more generalizable query?

Comment: Adding fields or tables dynamically will take dynamically generated SQL. You will need a stored procedure (or some other scripting language) to handle the addition of the new fields and the insertion into them.

Comment: This task is sometimes called "pivoting". It's a notorious pain in the neck in MySQL. Some other table servers offer query syntax to support pivoting.

Answer (score 1):

`PIVOT` (`CROSSTAB` in PostgreSQL) might be what you want to use. You are effectively simulating `PIVOT` in your query. However, for that you need to know all the attributes/columns you have.

If you don't know up-front these values, it's possible to construct such SQL programmatically (in a client, or some databases allow executing a generated string)